# Merging Percentage Lines with The Bars in Tableau Desktop

Tags: visualization, percentage, linechart, tableau-desktop, stacked-bar-chart

I have a graph that shows the ratio (count) of payable vs. processed words among the total words on  stacked bars. I would also like to display the same ratio in percentages in lines overlapping the bars.

[image: bars and lines graphs]

At the moment I have them in two separate graphs, but I want to merge them so that it takes less space in my dashboard view. I am unable to select the dual combination view as it requires two measures and even though I keep trying to cmd+click+drag the percentage measure pill to my marks, it's only changing the calculations in the bars but not allowing me to select the dual combination view.

[image: graph types selection]

Since the percentages are basically the ratio of the green/total in the bars, I don't think I need any complicated configurations for displaying it, however, I am also failing to achieve what I want.

Could you please tell me how to do this visualization?

Edit: I noticed that the reason I couldn't generate the dual combination view was that I had three date pills (year, quarter, month), and by removing two of them, I'm able to generate the dual combination view, but it's far from what I'm looking for as it's only splitting the stacked bar into bar+line.

[image: dual combination view]

Comment: For your second viz that is using the dual axis (green bars and blue lines overlapping), try editing your bar and line pills separately in the Marks pane instead of coloring on "All" . Also right click the right  axis and click *synchronize axis* for a bit more accuracy in reading the viz (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Neeku, I certainly understand the desire to minimize "real estate" in your dashboard. If I understand your needs correctly, I believe that overlaying a transparent-background chart over the first chart might meet your needs, if a dual-axis chart doesn't work for you (for example, if you wanted to overlay a line chart on a column chart that is itself already dual axis).

By way of example, here is a simple Sample Superstore dashboard with a line chart on top and a stacked column at the bottom.
[simple dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4cSr.png)

Change the line chart to "Floating"

[image: floating]

Size it to fit over your column chart and change the background to transparent by clicking anywhere in the line chart and select "Format"

[image: format]

...Format Shading

[image: format shading]

...and "None" for the color selection

[image: none]

Your line chart is now an overlay, but it's pretty messy.

[image: overlay]

Click on the line chart and hide field labels,

[image: hide field labels]

...turn off "Show Header" for each pill in the line chart

[image: turn off show header]

Clean things up and it should look better:

[image: cleaned up]

Note: one big issue with this approach is that you will not be able to click to select chart elements of the underlying chart.

Comment: If you find this informative, please upvote and mark as helpful.

Comment: Ok. So I am looking at your instructions now, and I believe it applies to when you have to separate worksheets for the bars and lines, is that right? If you look at my first photo, you'll see that I have both of those in one worksheet, so switching to 'floating' (and the rest of the steps) isn't possible. Or can I still somehow do this?